# What does {} mean in "xargs -I {} unrar x {}"?

Tags: macos, shell

I am new to shell and I'd like to learn, however, it seems a bit too complex to understand:

`find . \( -name *.rar \) | xargs -I {} unrar x {}`

Can you please explain step by step what is does. I know that it goes into folders and finds all the `.rar` files that it finds and then it chains the files that it finds into the second part of the command using `|` symbol.
However, I do not understand the `xargs -I {} unrar x {}` part, and `{}` command in particular. I know that `unrar` extracts the archive.

Comment: I think `man xargs` might help you.

Comment: See step-by-step explanation at  [explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+.+%5C%28+-name+*.rar+%5C%29+%7C+xargs+-I+%7B%7D+unrar+x+%7B%7D)

Comment: It's also pretty unnecessarily awful. There's no reason to write this to use `xargs` at all, given `find -exec`, and the use of xargs introduces bugs (look at what happens if you have a rar file with a space in its name.

Comment: Also, this won't work right if there are any `*.rar` files in the current directory, because the `*.rar` will be replaced with a list of filenames by your shell before it starts `find`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `{}` is a placeholder, replaced with a filename in the generated command.

However, **don't use this code**; it will behave badly with `rar` archives having unusual names, *or* if there are any files matching `*.rar` in the current directory (as opposed to subdirectories). Consider instead:

```
find . -name '*.rar' -exec unrar x '{}' ';'
```

...or, if you *really* want to use `xargs`:

```
find . -name '*.rar' -print0 | xargs -n 1 -0 unrar x
```